# What type is object which created by query expression?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 12, 56, 45, 65, 4, 6 };
b.Add(125);

IEnumerable<int> c = from n in b
                     where n < 60 && n > 12
                     select n;
```

Is `c` only references? What type is `from ... select n`?

Comment: I would suggest that you read about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c is of type:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[System.Int32]
```

You can see this by inspecting c.GetType();

If you want it to be evaluated and turned into an 'actual' list, you could try:

```
IEnumerable<int> c = (from n in b where n < 60 && n > 12 select n).ToList();
```

Comment: Side Note: c(only query) is kind of lazy evaluator, executed only when iterated. :)

Answer (score 0):

c is an Object of type `IEnumerable<int>`
it might be a List or any other collection.

Not a reference, anyway

ps : thank you  abatishchev

Comment: Is there any difference between `IEnumerable` and `System.Linq.Enumerable`?

Comment: I think, that the correct answer is: c is `System.Linq.Enumerable` which implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @FSou1 [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static class that provides several methods for creating and working with objects which implement `IEnumerable`. `IEnumerable` is the interface that represents a sequence of objects and allows you to use `foreach` to enumerate objects.

Comment: That's great, but `c.GetType()` returns me `System.Linq.Enumerable`

Comment: @FSou1 The type is actually `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<int>`. The `+` in the type name you get back from `c.GetType()` means that `WhereListIterator<int>` is a nested class of `System.Linq.Enumerable`.